# Update multiple documents by providing documents in body, mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to update several documents by providing them in the body. I can't query them, they must  be provided.

Example:

```
 var persons = [
    {id: 1, name'Joe', active: false}, 
    {id:2, name:'Jane', active: false})
];
```

This data is provided in the body and I want to set the active property to false.

```
exports.setActivePropertyOnPersons = function(input,callback){
  for(var i = 0;i<input.body.length;i++){
    mongoose.model('person').findOne({id:input.body[i].id}, function(err, person){
      person.active = false;
      person.save();
    })
  }
  callback.send(200)
};
```

This code feels no good. Is there any better query to do this? I don't find any in the docs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using the update command along with the "[$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)" operator:

```
var ids= [];
for (var i=0 i<input.body.length; ++i) {
    ids.push(input.body[i].id);
}

mongoose.model('person').update( {id : {"$in":ids}}, {active:false} , {multi: true} , function(err,docs) { ... });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the basic approach by selecting more than one document with `$in`, but the [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) command needs the ["multi"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) parameter in order to actually change more than the first document matched.

Comment: How would you handle different value's in the active variable?