# Mongoose update all documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema has array property. I want to modify each document's array property. For example, delete some elements from array. What's the best way to achieve such functionality?

Example:
User schema has array property with book names. At one moment I want to delete certain book names from each user. I want to achieve without functionality for each my user.

```
user.books = _.without(user.books, "SomeBookName1", "SomeBookName2", "SomeBookName3") //Underscore style:)
```

Comment: I found answers on similar questions:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689132/update-multiple-documents-by-providing-documents-in-body-mongoose-mongodb)
But they hardcoding property value. In my situation this property will differ.

Comment: Use the atomic update array operators whenever possible: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#array. But your question is too broad; can you edit it to show a specific update you're trying to make?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @JohnnyHK for help. `$pull` function from documentation helped me.

```
Model.update = function ({}, {$pull : {books: "someBookName" } }, {multi: true}, function(err) { //callback });
```

Or for deleting several items there is `$pullAll`.

```
$pullAll: {books: ["someBookName1", "someBookName2"]}
```